# Is there a generalisation of norm catering for $\|a\mathbf{v}\|=\|\mathbf{v}\|$?

Tags: soft-question, normed-spaces

I'm working with a function $p$ which gives a kind of "size" of the vectors in my vector space, and it has all the properties of a norm except that
$$p(a\mathbf{v})=p(\mathbf{v}).$$
Ordinarily a norm would have $p(a\mathbf{v})=|a|p(\mathbf{v}).$ Is there a generalisation of norm which caters for this type of situation? Or anyone know of any work dealing with this sort of situation?

The closest I have found is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Generalizations), where we can have
$$p(a\mathbf{v})=|a|^k p(\mathbf{v}),$$
where $0<k\leq 1$, but alas $k$ cannot be zero given the information on the web site.

**As an example**

Suppose $p((1,2,3,4,5))=\beta$, for some $\beta$, then the way my "size" function works is that for any $a\neq 0$, then $p(a(1,2,3,4,5))=p((1,2,3,4,5))=\beta$.

Comment: Is this only for $a\neq 0$? Otherwise you have $p({\bf v})=p(0{\bf v})=p(0)$ for all ${\bf v}$.

Comment: What's wrong with $p(\mathbf v) = 1$ for all $\mathbf v \ne \mathbf 0$?  You are essentially eliminating the notion of "scale" anyway, so the discrete metric seems a natural fit.  Is this more of a terminology question?

Comment: @kccu yes $a\neq 0$.

Comment: For example, suppose $p((1,2,3,4,5))=\beta$, for some $\beta$, then the way my "size" function works is that for any $a\neq 0$, then $p(a(1,2,3,4,5))=p((1,2,3,4,5))=\beta$. Just wondering if there is a generalisation of norm which deals with this situation. I'm not looking for a norm that fits the bill. I'd like to know if there is a generalisation of norm which caters for this situation.

Comment: What you seem to be talking about is a projective space.  In slightly less than rigorous terms, a projective space can be constructed by identifying all points by their scalar multiples.

Comment: @Erick Wong thanks for the comment. My "size" function $p$ applied to vectors in the vector space is not equal to $1$ for every vector in the vector space, but yes I can see that would fulfil the requirements if you wanted to find a norm with that property.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky thanks for this lead Michael. Just to clarify - are you saying I can define a suitable projective space, and then define a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on that space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be any real or complex vector space, $S$ the corresponding projective space (i.e. the equivalence classes of $V \backslash \{0\}$, where two elements are equivalent if they are scalar multiples of each other), and $\widehat{p}$ any positive real-valued function on $S$ such that $\sup_{s \in S} \widehat{p}(s) \le 2 \inf_{s \in S} \widehat{p}(s)$.  Then define $p$ on $V \backslash \{0\}$ by $p(v) = \widehat{p}([v])$, where $[v]$ is the equivalence class of $v$.  This obviously satisfies $p(\alpha v) = p(v)$ for nonzero scalars $\alpha$.
It also satisfies the triangle inequality since 
$$p(v+w) \le \sup_{s \in S} \widehat{p}(s) \le 2 \inf_{s \in S} \widehat{p}(s) \le p(v) + p(w)$$

On the other hand, suppose  $p$ is continuous on $V \backslash \{0\}$ (in some topology in which $V$ is a topological vector space) and satisfies the triangle inequality and your $p(\alpha v) = p(v)$.  Then I claim $p$ is of the above form.  It suffices to prove that for any $v, w$ we have $p(w) \le 2 p(v)$.  Suppose this is not the case, so there are $v, w$ with $p(w) > 2 p(v)$.    Take $0 < \epsilon < p(w) - 2 p(v)$.  For $u$ in some neighbourhood $U$ of $v$ we have $p(u) < p(v) + \epsilon$.  Now take
$ u = (1-s) v + s w$ where $0 < s < 1$ is small enough that $u \in U$.
Then we have $w = \dfrac{1}{s} u + \dfrac{s-1}{s} v$, so we get the contradiction $$p(w) \le p\left(\dfrac{1}{s} u\right) + p\left(\dfrac{s-1}{s} v\right) = p(u) + p(v)
< 2 p(v) + \epsilon < p(w)$$

You do have discontinuous examples not of this form.  For example, with $V = \mathbb R^n$ you could take 
$$ p(v) = \cases{ 1 & if $v_1 = 0$\cr
                  3 & otherwise\cr}$$